# Multilingual links in Blade Laravel

Tags: laravel, multilingual, laravel-blade

I'm translating a Laravel site which is using Blade templates and was wondering if there is a better way to translate a link as shown below:

**app/lang/en/contact.php:**

```
return [
    '1' => 'text before link',
    '2' => 'link text',
    '3' => 'text after link'
];
```

**app/views/contact.blade.php:**

```
<p>{{ Lang::get('contact.1') }} 
      <a herf="{{URL::route('home')}}">{{ Lang::get('contact.2') }}</a> 
{{ Lang::get('contact.3') }}}</p>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What about this solution?

**blade template:**

```
{!! Lang::get('test.test', [ 'url' => 'http://stackoverflow.com/' ]) !!}
```

**lang/test.php**

```
<?php
return [
    'test' => '<a href=":url">My Pretty Link</a>'
]
```

Comment: This is the best solution

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 6):

You could use the URL as a parameter and you would only need one translation entry:

**app/lang/en/contact.php**

```
return [
    '1' => 'text before link <a href=":url">link text</a>text after link'
];
```

**app/views/contact.blade.php**

```
<p>{{ Lang::get('contact.1', URL::route('home')) }}</p>
```

**Downside**: you have HTML in your translations

An other way to make your code cleaner (but doesn't change your translations in any way) would be using Laravels [HTML link helper](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#urls) and `trans()` (Alias for `Lang::get()`

```
<p>
    {{ trans('contact.1') }}
    {{ link_to_route('home', trans('contact.2')) }}
    {{ trans('contact.3') }}
</p>
```

Comment: Cool, this trans() and link_to_route() does look better in a blade template, are there solutions like that for <strong>, <b> and <span>? can't find them.

Comment: No there aren't. But I don't think it needs them. `<strong>test</strong>` vs `{{ strong('test') }}`... Blade is not meant to replace HTML. However if you really want to, you can just write your own function.

Comment: "but doesn't change your translations in any way" That is not entirely right. Different languages have different order of sentence so every language will have different content of `contact.1`, `contact.2` and `contact.3`. And all 3 are needed for ALL links, as some english sentences may just end with link, but different languages may want to put link in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution for this problem:

- resources/lang/en/contact.php:

  ```
  <?php

  return [
      'sentence' => 'please :click here',
      'click' => 'CLICK',
  ];
  ```
- blade template:

  ```
  @section('click link')
      <a href="{{ url('/contact') }}">
          {{ trans('contact.click') }}
      </a>
  @overwrite

  {!! trans('contact.sentence', ['click' => view()->yieldContent('click link')]) !!}
  ```